Quickest known integer relation algorithm in the case of signs
Let $x_1,\cdots,x_n,k$ be integers such that $|k|\le\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|$.
What is the quickest known algorithm to determine $w_i\in\{-1,0,1\}$ such that $k=\sum_{i=1}^nw_ix_i$ where they exist?
What is its asymptotic as $n\to\infty$?
These algorithms apply more generally to $w_i\in\Bbb Z$ and $x_i\in\Bbb R$ so perhaps this case has a faster algorithm.
 Previously posted on Operations Research Stack Exchange with no response.

Just to note, it's possible to solve the problem in $\approx 3^{n/2}$ time using an algorithm similar to the $2^{n/2}$-time meet-in-the-middle algorithm for Subset Sum.

I don't think you're going to get a single answer.  I expect there are multiple algorithms, each most effective in a different portion of the problem space.  Beyond integer linear programming and methods for finding integer relations, I expect that many of the algorithms for the partition problem or subset sum problem can potentially be adapted to your problem as well.
